# VBScript dictionary item pass byref

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I am doing some ASP Classic with VBScript. I am doing something like the following,

```
Public Sub testFunc(ByRef a)
    a=10
End Sub

Public Function createDict()
    Set createDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    createDict.Add "foo",0
End Function

Set b = createDict()
testFunc b("foo")
Response.Write(b.Item("foo")) 'The result is 0, instead of 10
```

I am wondering how to create a function/sub that can **modify** the dictionary item. Is it possible to do so in VBScript?

Even I tried with

```
Set c = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
c.Add "foo",0
testFunc c("foo")
Response.Write(c("foo"))
```

It doesn't work either.

Comment: You could probably do this by creating the dictionary as a global variable (outside the scope of any given function).

Comment: @Tim, it does not work, even I try this:
Set c = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
c.Add "foo",0
testFunc c("foo")
Response.Write(c("foo"))

Answer (score 2):

If you use an expression like `collection(index)` in other contexts than left of an assignment (=), you get a (copy of the) value of the collection's element at that index. So a Sub or Function to change an element must get the collection, the index, and the new value via its parameter list.

Comment: that is a real shame. so there is now way around two lookups if i want to increment a dictionary item? i was hoping to write an inc function with a byval parameter, didnt work, landed here.

Answer (score 1):

As far as VBScript goes the below works just fine for me...

```
Sub Test()
Dim X, W
Set X = Nothing
Set X = PassDictionary
If Not X Is Nothing Then
    For Each W In X.Keys
        MsgBox W & " : " & X.Item(W)
    Next
End If
End Sub

Function PassDictionary()
Dim objDic
Set objDic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
objDic.Add "One", objDic.Count + 1
objDic.Add "Two", objDic.Count + 1
objDic.Add "Three", objDic.Count + 1
Set PassDictionary = objDic
End Function
```

EDIT:  By adding an additional Argument and passing the Dictionary object itself to the "testfunc" routine I was able to modify the Dictionary Object.

```
Public Sub testFunc(a, b)
    a(b) = 10
End Sub

Public Function createDict()
    Set createDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    createDict.Add "foo", 0
End Function

Set b = createDict()
Call testFunc(b, "foo")
Response.Write (b.Item("foo"))
```

Comment: The question was how to pass dictionary **items** by reference, not how to pass the dictionary itself by reference.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - Added Additional code to pass and modify the Dictionary Item...